# AntiXssEncoder in web.config messes up default encoding scheme

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, character-encoding

I've setup a basic MVC 4 app to use the AntiXssEncoder in the web.config per some old [instructions](http://idunno.org/archive/2011/09/14/net-4-5-now-includes-the-core-antixss-functions.aspx). When I do this though the application characters that would normally be encoded are no longer encoded correctly.

Is there anyway to correct this unacceptable behavior in the web.config or is this library just broken?

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" encoderType="System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder,System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

**MVC4 default web.config:**
*This exhibits expected behavior*

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>No encoding</td>
        <td>Inside Microsoft&#174; SharePoint&#174; 2013</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Inside Microsoft® SharePoint® 2013")</td>
        <td>Inside Microsoft&amp;#174; SharePoint&amp;#174; 2013</td> <!-- double encoded, expected result -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode("Inside Microsoft® SharePoint® 2013")</td>
        <td>Inside Microsoft&#174; SharePoint&#174; 2013</td><!-- manual call to encode, expected result -->
    </tr>
</table>
```

**AntiXssEncoder setup in web.config:**
*This is **NOT** the expected behavior. None of the copyright symbols have been encoded correctly.*

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>No encoding</td>
        <td>Inside Microsoft® SharePoint® 2013</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Inside Microsoft® SharePoint® 2013")</td>
        <td>Inside Microsoft® SharePoint® 2013</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode("Inside Microsoft® SharePoint® 2013")</td>
        <td>Inside Microsoft® SharePoint® 2013</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Source code reference:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>No encoding</td>
        <td>@data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Inside Microsoft® SharePoint® 2013")</td>
        <td>@HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(data)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode("Inside Microsoft® SharePoint® 2013")</td>
        <td>@System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(data, false)</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find old resources where the AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode() would only have a string as the parameter. However looking at [MSDN - AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(string,boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh244070(v=vs.110).aspx), the result you got is expected.

The registered trademark character is part of the safe characters ([C1 Controls and Latin-1 Supplement](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf)), hence it won't be encoded.

If you call the method passing true for the useNamedEntities parameter, the registered trademark will be converted to & reg;

You can refer to the code below - also on [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MHwkg4)

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security.AntiXss;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string data = "Inside Microsoft® SharePoint® 2013";

        Console.WriteLine(" -- HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(data) --");
        Console.WriteLine(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(data));

        Console.WriteLine(" -- AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(data, false) --");
        Console.WriteLine(AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(data, false));

        Console.WriteLine(" -- AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(data, true) --");
        Console.WriteLine(AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(data, true));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML characters are automatically encoded in MVC Razorview.
You need not call HTMLencoder explicitly for the parameters that has an @ prefixed to them.